# A question about a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, cauchy-integral-formula, holomorphic-functions

A complex-valued function $f$ is said to be in $\mathcal{F}_a$ if it is holomorphic and satisfies $|f(z=x+iy)|\leq\frac{A}{1+x^2}$, where $A$ is a real constant in $\{z\in \mathbb C: \vert\mathrm{Im}(z)\vert\leq a\}$. I have to show that $f^{(n)}\in \mathcal F_b$ for all $0\leq b<a$.

I have realized that Cauchy's integral formula may be used to solve the problem. But I could not proceed further. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What means $A$ is a real constant in $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|Im(z)|\leq a\}$?.

Comment: @MyGlasses, the *inequality* is true in the stripe.

Comment: holomorphic where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r=b-a$. Then, for every $z=x+iy$, with $|y|<b$, Cauchy Integral Formula provides
$$
f^{(n)}(x+iy)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|w-z|=r}\frac{f(w)\,dw}{(w-z)^{n+1}}
$$
and hence
$$
|\,f^{(n)}(x+iy)|\le \frac{n!}{r^n}\max_{|w-z|=r} |\,f(w)|\le \frac{n!}{r^n}\cdot \frac{A}{1+(x-r)^2}. 
$$
But
$$
\frac{1}{1+(x-r)^2}\le\frac{r^2+2}{1+x^2}
$$
and hence
$$
|\,f^{(n)}(x+iy)|\le \frac{n!A(r^2+2)}{r^n}\cdot\frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$
for every $(x,y)\in \mathbb R\times (-b,b)$.